# Shared resources in Windows Server 2008 were lost

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

We have an Oracle database in Windows Server 2003, which has its archived redo logs stored on a shared resource of a Windows Server 2008:

`\\192.168.1.189\d$\folder_for_archivedlogs`

However, according to Oracle's `alert.log`, at 10:01 p.m that shared resource got lost and the database was inaccessible. From my Windows Server 2003, on Windows Explorer, I couldn't access that shared resource, but I got a response when I did `ping 192.168.1.189`.

I reviewed all the Event Logs on that Windows 2008, but there is no error at 10:00pm or 11:00pm.

Has anyone seen some similar case before? (Shared resources get lost, but you still can ping the server and there are no error events in the Event Logs).

Comment: Yes.  All that a ping response tells you is that the machine is capable of replying to pings; it doesn't say anything about the about the availability of system resources, file shares or anything else.

Comment: Have you checked the folder still exists on the server's hard drive?

Comment: Actually I don't understand why this questions gets -1. I don't find any clue on google, and am just asking if someone experienced a similar situation.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - Gosh I wish people would stop using ping as an application/service troubleshooting tool.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question (on my part), but you never know... is the server's IP address static or dynamic?  If it's dynamic, has a reservation been configured on the DHCP server?

A ping only tells you that *a* device is answering at that address, not necessarily *the* server in question.

Also, just curious why you've chosen to access the share via IP address vs. hostname?  If the server's address were to change (either dynamically or manually), you'd need to re-point clients to the new address... if you were to use the hostname, you'll have eliminated that problem.

Comment: Both servers have static IP. In our case, IP for servers are very unlikely to be changed. I also thought that Antivirus could affected shared resource, but nothing is in Mcafee alert.log.